# Attempt to invoke virtual method void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a problem if u want see and help me ;)
I'm a student and I don't understand why my recyclerView has a null result.
If you have a solution it will be appreciated.

The Glide annotation in the adapter is an idea because the goal I am looking to do is to retrieve inforamations (url) from Firebase cloud then to store this url in a list then use Glide in order to retrieve the imae instead of url. If you think there is better to do then I am here to learn :)

Thanks

my Holder :

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import fr.jaroddeveloppement.vistacard.R;

public class HolderCard extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mImageView;



    public HolderCard(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageCard);
    }
}
```

my Adapter :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import fr.jaroddeveloppement.vistacard.R;
import fr.jaroddeveloppement.vistacard.activity.CreateCard;
import fr.jaroddeveloppement.vistacard.model.CardModel;
import fr.jaroddeveloppement.vistacard.model.recyclerview.HolderCard;

public class CardAdapteur extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HolderCard> {


    CreateCard createCard;
    ArrayList<CardModel> mCardModelArrayList;
    private static final String Tag ="RecyclerView";

    String url;

    /** constructor
     * @param pCreateCard
     * @param pCardModelArrayList
     */
    public CardAdapteur(CreateCard pCreateCard, ArrayList<CardModel> pCardModelArrayList) {
        createCard = pCreateCard;
        mCardModelArrayList = pCardModelArrayList;
    }





    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HolderCard onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View lvView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_create_card, parent, false);
        return new HolderCard(lvView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderCard holder, int position) {

        CardModel cardModel = mCardModelArrayList.get(position);

        holder.mImageView.setText(cardModel.getUrl());
        //Glide.with(mContext).load(mCardModelArrayList.get(position).getQuery()).into(holder.mImageView);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCardModelArrayList.size();
    }
}
```

My Activity :

```
 * Copyright (c) 2022.
 */

package fr.jaroddeveloppement.vistacard.activity;



import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import android.os.Bundle;

;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import fr.jaroddeveloppement.vistacard.R;
import fr.jaroddeveloppement.vistacard.model.CardModel;
import fr.jaroddeveloppement.vistacard.model.adapter.CardAdapteur;



public class CreateCard extends AppCompatActivity  {


    TextView mImageView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseFirestore mFirebaseFirestore;
    CardAdapteur cardAdapteur;
    ArrayList<CardModel> cardModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;







    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_card);

        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageCard);


        mFirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewModelCard);


        //setUpRecyclerView();

        GetDataFromFirebase();
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(cardAdapteur);





    }

    public void setUpRecyclerView(){

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    }
    public void GetDataFromFirebase() {

     mFirebaseFirestore.collection("ModelCard").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
             for (DocumentSnapshot doc :task.getResult()){
                 CardModel cardModel = new CardModel(doc.getString("url"));
                 cardModel.getUrl();


                 cardModelArrayList.add(cardModel);
             }

             cardAdapteur = new CardAdapteur(CreateCard.this,cardModelArrayList );

         }
     });

    }
}
```

and my xml :

````
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewModelCard"/>
</LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>```
````

Comment: I think the problem is that you create instance of CardAdapteur in asynchronous call, so it's created after you set adapter in RecyclerView. This means that RecyclerView is initialized with adapter, which has null value.

Comment: @Myroslav Thank you for your answer I also think that the LayoutManager should be placed before the creation of the adapter. So I put just after the onCreate but that does not change the error :(.   ```@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_card);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewModelCard);
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageCard);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));```

Comment: So have you solved the problem? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Ok, below may be not the best solution, but it should help. Please put those 3 lines `layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(cardAdapteur);` after `cardAdapteur = new CardAdapteur(CreateCard.this,cardModelArrayList );`

Comment: @AlexMamo Hi, yes I just solved the problem is that I was missing a Layout for it to work. I was looking to put my imageView and my recyclerView on the same Layout so it couldn't exist to fit it. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @Myroslav Hi, yes I just solved the problem is that I was missing a Layout for it to work. I was looking to put my imageView and my recyclerView on the same Layout so it couldn't exist to fit it. Thanks for your help ;)